# How to query Custom Object in Salesforce?

Tags: java, android, salesforce

Ok, I am reposting this question because it really drives me crazy.

I have enterprise.wsdl downloaded from salesforce and generated to some jars.

I build path those jars to my Android project in Eclipse.

Here is my code:

```
ConnectorConfig config = new ConnectorConfig();
config.setAuthEndpoint(authEndPoint);
config.setUsername(userID);
config.setPassword(password + securityToken);
config.setCompression(true);
con = new EnterpriseConnection(config);
con.setSessionHeader(UserPreference.getSessionID(mContext));
String sql = "SELECT something FROM myNameSpace__myCustomObject__c"; 
con.query(sql);
```

but it returns me this error:

> [InvalidSObjectFault [ApiQueryFault [ApiFault
>   exceptionCode='INVALID_TYPE' exceptionMessage='sObject type 'abc__c'
>   is not supported.'] row='-1' column='-1' ]]

I am pretty sure that my userID has been assigned with profile that has read, edit access to that custom object.

My code also can query standard object.

Anyone can advise me what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

From what I know there are three reasons it may give this error.
1. User permission which you said is setup correctly.
2. Do you have the custom object deployed to the org where you are trying to establish the connection?
3. Check the enterprise WSDL if it contains the custom object name which you are trying to query.

Hope it helps.